# Deferred jquery script is loading after all the others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my  I have some js that I'm defering as that seems to be best practice.

Load it in the head and make the JS defer if it isn't anything that *must* be there.

My scripts are basic, Bootstrap stuff:

```
    <script defer src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="/static/font-awesome-5/js/fontawesome-all.min.js"></script>
```

But when I load the page, it's loading jquery slim *last* which is causing issues on some of our other pages that have additional scripts (again, loaded in the head, but after jquery) - which use jquery as a requirement.

I have even tried bringing the JS into our static folder (similar to what we're doing with Font Awesome); but it still continues to load after everything else.

What's the best way to correct that?

Comment: Why are you deferring the scripts?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32413657/2181514

Comment: Looks like you've failed your own assertion.  "defer if it isn't anything that *must* be there" - looks like jquery must indeed be there.

Comment: Everything I have read online says it's best practice to defer any scripts that are being loaded in the head if they are not important during the loading of the page - @Mikey

Comment: Basically: `defer` says "start loading this and parse it when loaded".  If you defer multiple scripts, the later ones might finish loading before the first (jquery) so will be parsed first.

Comment: jquery isn't needed until 'after the DOM load', which is the point of the defer tag: to defer parsing the scripts after the DOM has loaded. But after the DOM has loaded, the scripts *should* parse in they order they are listed in the DOM if the defer tag is used. So from all I can find, it should be working.

Comment: No, jquery is needed *before* your other scripts (eg bootstrap) are parsed.  Can you provide information that states they "parse in order they are listed"?  It looks like they are parsed in order they are *loaded*.

Comment: More: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15099465/2181514

Comment: Although this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script states *Scripts with the defer attribute will execute in the order in which they appear in the document.*.  Shouldn't be hard to test with a server-side delay.

Comment: But the evidence (this question) says otherwise...

Comment: That's my point. I'm looking for someone who can maybe clarify for me why documentation that exists out there states it should load them in the appropriate order, but it's not happening here. That's why I posted the question - because my results go against what the documentation says. I can't see why, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite all the documentation saying it *should* work that way I was doing it, I ended up just going the route of moving the scripts to the bottom of the page and no longer use the `defer` attribute